# populating Spinner nested in ListView Rows (Android)

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a list view where each row displays the name of some inventory item, its quantity available, and a spinner to select the amount of the item to buy (when clicking make purchase at the bottom of the page, the selected amount of each spinner is grabbed and processed).

I currently have a loop that iterates over the rows and grabs the spinner by its identifier. It uses the position of the row to access another array that contains the corresponding qty of the item show in this position. It uses this qty as a stopping point for another nested loop that creates an ArrayList of numbers up to the given qty (so a user cannot select more than what is available). The ArrayList is then popped into a custom ArrayAdapter as the data field but for some reason the ArrayAdapter is not populating the spinner. What's missing??

Heres the relevant code

```
public class PlaceOrder extends Activity {

ArrayList<Item> items;
ArrayList<Customer> customers;
int position;

ListView orderList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_order);

    Intent data = getIntent();
    items = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("items");
    customers = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("customers");
    position = data.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    orderList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.purchaseList);
    PurchasedItemAdapter itemAdapter = new PurchasedItemAdapter(this, R.layout.purchase_table_row, items);
    orderList.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    for (int i = 0; i < orderList.getCount(); i++) {
        View view = orderList.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.purchase_table_spinner);
        int stop = items.get(i).qtyAvailable;
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int k = 0; k <= stop; k++) {
            stringList.add(String.format("%d", k));
        }
        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringList);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    }



}
```

Adapter Class...

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<String> data = null;

public SpinnerAdapter (Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.qty = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.simple_spinner_text);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    holder.qty.setText(data.get(position));

    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView qty;
}
```

}

Listview Adapter..

```
public class PurchasedItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Item> data = null;

public PurchasedItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Item> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ItemHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ItemHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.purchase_table_itemName);
        holder.qty = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.purchase_table_qty);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ItemHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Item item = data.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(item.name);
    holder.qty.setText(String.format("%d", item.qtyAvailable));

    return row;
}

static class ItemHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView qty;

}
```

}

Comment: please post the code of PurchasedItemAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PurchasedItemAdapter is your custom list adapter spinnerAdapter for each row(if the spinner is not same for each row) is suitable to set inside the PurchasedItemAdapter class or at least it is better to set spinner adapter before PurchasedItemAdapter 
" the selected amount of each spinner is grabbed and processed" so each row of your list has a spinner why don't you set it inside PurchaseItemAdapter and add a spinner item in view Holder class as well...I would do so

Comment: I assigned the spinner adapter to the spinner inside the PurchasedItemAdapter and everything is working now. Thanks man

Comment: how would i notify the spinner's adapter that the data set has changed when I select some row from some spinner?